# Creating a ImageReader without width/height

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-graphics

When I try and create an imageReader of type depth point cloud, I get a null object.

The reason for this is that I've adapted code from `Camera2Basic` for this and it gets the largest output size from the stream configuration map. The issue is that since it is a point cloud, there is not a sensible width and height to output. Hence it returns null width and height, resulting in a null imageReader:

```
Size largest = Collections.max(
        Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.DEPTH_POINT_CLOUD)),//Returning null
        new CompareSizesByArea());

mDMImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(), ImageFormat.DEPTH_POINT_CLOUD, 2);
```

Hence the only solution that I can really see is if there is a way of creating an imageReader for a Depth Point Cloud format, unfortunately I can't see a way of doing this since it requires there to be a width and height which obviously there can't be. Hence my issue.

Thanks for any help and advice you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong you can't create a ImageReader with null width and height. The reason is that as you can read in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html#newInstance(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) the values that you set as height and width are the default size values for every image that that ImageReader will generate.

I suggest you to use your preview width and height values(that you should have stored in some variable or dynamically calculated in some place), or the biggest value that you device can support. You can calculate the Image sizes that your camera device support using:

```
    private static List<Size> getOutputSizes(CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics, Object kind) {
         //my kind value is ImageFormat.JPEG in this example
          StreamConfigurationMap streamConfigurationMap = cameraCharacteristics
             .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
          if (streamConfigurationMap != null) {
             Size[] availableResolutionsArray;
             //The parameter is either an Integer (JPEG) or a class (MediaRecorder.class)
             if (kind instanceof Integer) {
                availableResolutionsArray = streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes((Integer) kind);
             } else {
                availableResolutionsArray = streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes((Class) kind);
             }
             List<Size> availableResolutions = Arrays.asList(availableResolutionsArray);    

             return availableResolutions;
          } else {
             return Collections.singletonList(new Size(DEFAULT_WIDHT, DEFAULT_HEIGHT));
          }
       }
```